# In Pgfplots, 'contour prepared' is not showing contour lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, contour

I'm trying to plot a 2D contour using pfgplot. The way of contour lines executions is inappropriate. I need to plot black/white smooth contour for 10 levels with self-labeled.
Please help me with this query. Thanks in advance.

data file

[here is the data file link](https://tinyurl.com/ycyzvdhk)

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{contour}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    
      \pgfplotsset{}

    \begin{axis}[]
            \addplot[contour prepared={labels=false}, contour prepared format =standard]
                    table[col sep=comma] {t2e.csv};
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Contours with label]

[image: Contours withot label]